# Find the index of an entry using a key in unix

Tags: csv, unix, awk, grep

I have a key which is a string `key="Value1"`

I then have a file.csv which I would like to search with the key. Using the key I want to find the row entry in the csv file, then find the column position of "Value2" in the identified row.

I tried using:

```
$ awk 's=index($0,$key) { print "line=" NR }' file.csv
```

But that doesn't seem to work as it basically identifies all the rows :P

I thought grep might work but not sure how to effectively implement it

Input: file.csv

```
Value, Object, Position, Value!
Value1, Object1, Position, Value2
```

Desired Output:

```
row 2 col 4
```

where col number is stored as a variable x, where e.g. x = 4

Comment: Please give some sample input and desired output.

Comment: I've tried awk but the key doesn't seem to effectively identify the right index position.

Comment: So you want to produce that output but also store one part as a shell variable?

Comment: If you know you're looking for 'Value1' how do you know you need the column for 'Value2'?

Comment: I've also tried grep $key file.csv

Comment: Yeah Tom, because I want to pass that to a another script later, I'm not looking for value1 I want to use "Value1" as the key, which then finds the row entry, where I then search for the column position of "Value2", I do this because "Value2" is not unique, but "Value1" is, and I need the column index where "Value2" is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think that you can use something like this:

```
awk -F', *' -v key="Value1" -v value="Value2" '$1 == key { 
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) if ($i == value) { print i; exit } }' file
```

This passes two values to the awk script: the key, which is used to determine the correct row and the value which is to be searched for. When the first field matches the key, a loop goes through the rest of the fields and outputs the first one that matches the value. When one is found, the script exits.

To assign the value to a shell variable `x`, use `x=$(awk ...)`.

Comment: Looks good, although I think the OP wants `print "row", NR, "col", i"` there.

Comment: @Jeff yeah, I wasn't sure whether it was best to provide the number that the OP planned on using directly here or printing the output as you have suggested but then having to parse it later. The "desired output" seemed like more of a debugging step to me.